# How to inform Google Cloud security that external network traffic is expected?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-app-engine

My platform has a function that sends traffic out, crawls for data and retrieve them back into my platform. Google cloud informed me that they suspect that platform was compromised etc but that was not the case. I also noted the feedback by them - “you can fix the problem by ensuring that your project traffic directed at third parties is expected and that your project has not been compromised".

The question is, how do I setup related configuration for the above step?

Answer (score 1):

Not totally sure what do you mean by "inform" but this should be fixable creating a good [firewall rule.](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#specifications),

If you have the port that your app is using and it's public IP, you should be able to whitelist that traffic with the firewall rule.

but, also keep in mind that depending on the type of machine you have, the maximum amount of connections will vary.